# SSL error python3

Tags: python3, anaconda

Up until yesterday I've been using Spyder on Anaconda (windows) to run code with no issues whatsoever. Today, while running one of my scripts that include quandl, I get an SSL error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.quandl.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/datasets/WIKI/EIX/data?order=asc
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

I then uninstalled my Anaconda and installed the most recent version, and am now getting an HTTP error:

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2

It seems that every request is being denied (including any other package I attempt to upgrade or install using pip or conda including pip and conda themselves).

Does anybody have any clue as to what is happening?

Comment: Please provide more specifics on the certificate.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to acquire details about the certificate. This is an error i get when i run a quandl.get ("stockdata") request in spyder. The second error (conda) is when I try to install quandl in the Anaconda environment using the Anaconda prompt. It seems like all requests to external servers are failing. Note: my internet connection is fine, and i can indeed use quandl in R. This problem seems to be exclusive to the Anaconda environment although nothing has changed.